# Is it possible to redirect one cloudfront.net link to another?

Tags: redirect, amazon-cloudfront

We have a Cloudfront.net link which is returning a 404 status.
How can I redirect the bad link to a good link?
Thanks,
Josh

Comment: The simplest solution is to fix this on the origin server, behind CloudFront.  What is actually serving the content?

Comment: @Michael-sqlbot this is coming from the site's S3 bucket. It looks like there are two distributions for this site, so should I remove one? How do I determine which one is in use?
The link is http://d31hzlhk6di2h5.cloudfront.net/20161107/bc/58/43/6f/0c510fa0ed16b8a1ed1804ee_560x144.png
But the two distributions for this site are:
E2D7YLLK7K0T1B and E2NA1MDBIOMOZJ.